# How can I update one table in reference to another table in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Here is how I have my tables set up -

```
Products
_______

P_Id  Desc  
1      Apple  
2     Orange  
3     Banana


Categories
__________

P_Id  Cat_Id  
1      200  
2      200  
3      205
```

Now I need to update the field 'Desc' field from table "Products" where 'Cat_Id' field from table "Categories" is equal to 200. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)?

Comment: "Now I need to update the field 'Desc' field" Update it to what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
UPDATE Products
SET `desc` = 'foo'
WHERE P_id IN (SELECT P_Id FROM Categories WHERE Cat_Id = 200)
```

Another approach is to use a multiple-table update

```
UPDATE Products, Categories
SET Products.`desc` = 'foo'
WHERE Products.P_id = Categories.P_ID
AND Categories.Cat_Id = 200
```

By the way, `desc` is a very poor choice for the name of a column. It is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html). All the time saved by not typing `description` in full will be quickly lost when you have to debug  queries that don't work when you forget the backticks.

Comment: Thanks a million. Thanks for the 'Desc' tip as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE products
set `Desc` = 'xxx'
WHERE P_id IN (SELECT P_Id FROM Categories WHERE Cat_Id = 200);
```

Comment: You need backticks round `desc` - it is a reserved word.

Comment: oops i missed it.. Thanks.. :-)